# How to push into a StackView recursively QML?

Tags: qt, qml, stackview

I have a `StackView` and an item which I want to push every time I click a button. It works only the first time I press a button, I can understand there is an issue with parent-child relationship. But how to fix it?

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    StackView{
        id: stackView
        anchors.fill: parent

        initialItem: Item {
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height
            FirstLevel {
                myModel: 5
                onButtonClicked: {
                    stackView.push("qrc:/FirstLevel.qml", {myModel: 5})
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**FirstLevel.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Column {
    property var myModel

    signal buttonClicked()

    Repeater {
        model: myModel

        Button {
            text: model.index
            onClicked: {
                buttonClicked()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE I**

I want to push `FirstLevel.qml` item into a stackview every time I click a button in the `FirstLevel.qml` item.

Comment: Explain better what you want.

Comment: @eyllanesc please check out my update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do the push in the FirstLevel.qml:

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    StackView{
        id: stackView
        anchors.fill: parent

        initialItem: Item {
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height
            FirstLevel {
                myModel: 5
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**FirstLevel.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Column {
    property var myModel
    Repeater {
        model: myModel
        Button {
            text: model.index
            onClicked: {
                stackView.push("qrc:/FirstLevel.qml", {myModel: myModel})
            }
        }
    }
}
```